# Eclipse SBT Dependency Library

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, ivyde, sbteclipse

After I want to use activator eclipse commond, I should see the project with all jars in SBT Dependency Library container with eclipse project,Just like Maven Dependencies container.How to do it? or do not sbteclipse plugin have the function?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

1. Make sure you have sbteclipse configured as described [here](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse).

   You could add this to your sbt configuration at `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt`:

   ```
   addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "3.0.0")
   ```
2. Create a scala app with activator

   ```
   activator new minimal-scala minimal-scala
   ...
   OK, application "hello-world" is being created using the "minimal-scala" template.
   ...
   ```
3. Compile and run the application

   ```
   cd hello-world
   activator run
   ...
   [info] Running com.example.Hello 
   Hello, world!
   [success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jun 11, 2015 8:50:20 PM
   ```
4. Create the eclipse project with activator

   ```
   activator eclipse
   [info] Set current project to hello-world (in build file:/Users/...)
   [info] About to create Eclipse project files for your project(s).
   [info] Successfully created Eclipse project files for project(s):
   [info] hello-world
   ```

   This will create the `.project` and `.classpath` files that eclipse needs.
5. Now import the project in Eclipse

   - Select from the menu: `File > Import...`
   - Type `ex` in the text field that filters project types and select `Existing Projects into Workspace`
   - Select your project folder with `Browse...` button and click Finish

   Now you should see your project in eclipse with all dependencies that are in your sbt build specification (e.g. `build.sbt`). The sbt dependencies come up in `Referenced Libraries`.
6. When you want to change your dependencies, you

   - edit your `build.sbt`
   - run `activator eclipse` again
   - select the project in Eclipse and refresh (e.g. hit F5 key or right click and `refresh`)

Comment: sorry,That is not my question which you understand.I must add the sbteclipse plugin , after we run the 'eclipse' commond with activator,we can import the project into eclipse,but in the eclipse project explorer,we can see all dependency jar display in the root directory.I want to take all jar into a container,when I run the eclipse commond.